# How to set full width for image in mPDF php?

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I am using mPDF to convert the HTML to PDF. I have added code like below.

```
$mPdf = new Mpdf();  <html><head>
  <style>
     @page { 
     sheet-size:3.7cm 4cm;
     margin: 0;   
     }
     .adlayout {
     position: absolute;
     overflow: hidden;
     overflow-wrap: break-word;
     border: 1px solid;
     }
     .w-full {
     width: 100%;
     }           
     .relative {
     position: relative!important;
     }
     .h-auto {
     height: auto;
     }
  </style></head><body><div class="adlayout " ><img alt="editor_preview_image"  class="w-full relative h-auto " src="https://personal-shurn.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/tiny2pdf/images/Dahlia-Coralie.96.189.5.jpg"/>
  </div></body></html> $mPdf->WriteHTML($texttt);$mPdf->Output("response.pdf", Destination::FILE);
```

but full image width is not applying to the image and attached pdf image.

[image]

(Image in the pdf and width is not 100%)

Comment: Take a look at margins https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/construct.html